# My current time and my TimePicker time are ~40.000seconds off (yesterday it was+46.803, today it is -39.598 seconds off)

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I cannot upload it if its only code without details thats why i had all the comments

```java
public class Wecker extends AppCompatActivity {
    TextView Alarm1;
    long AlarmTime,currentTime;
    int A1Stunde,A1Minute,year,month,day;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_wecker);


        //timePicker for AlarmTime


        Alarm1 = findViewById(R.id.Alarm1);
        Alarm1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                TimePickerDialog timePickerDialog = new TimePickerDialog(
                        Wecker.this,
                        new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int Stunde, int Minute) {
                                A1Stunde = Stunde;
                                A1Minute = Minute;

                                Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
                                calendar.set(0,0,0,A1Stunde,A1Minute);

                                Alarm1.setText(DateFormat.format("hh:mm aa",calendar));

                            }
                        },24,0,true

                );
                //converts the timePickerDialog time into Millis

                timePickerDialog.updateTime(A1Stunde,A1Minute);
                timePickerDialog.show();
                Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
                year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
                month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
                day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
                c.set(Calendar.HOUR, A1Stunde);
                c.set(Calendar.MINUTE, A1Minute);
                c.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
                c.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
                AlarmTime = (c.getTimeInMillis() / 1000);
            }
        });

        //Timer to compare the currentTime with the AlarmTime


        Timer t = new Timer();
        t.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                //currenTime form calendar


                currentTime = Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis() / 1000;

                if (currentTime==AlarmTime) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "works");

                }else{

                    Log.e(TAG, String.valueOf(currentTime));
                    Log.e(TAG, String.valueOf(AlarmTime));
                }}
        },0,1000);
```

Today the value of the AlarmTime is off by -39.598 seconds yesterday it was +46.803 i dont have any clue why this is happening or how i can fix it. Is it something because of the TimeZones or something about AM / PM time and if so how could it work?

Comment: pls fix your code formatting, first paste the code then select everything and click the code button in the top of the stackoverflow UI, that should help get your code into a readable format

Comment: better like that? I'm knew to Stackoverflow and not sure how everything works sorry.

Comment: Format code with enclosing with 3 backticks or by indenting with four spaces. I fixed yours this time.

Comment: You have a lot of code there. Can you strip that down to the bare minimum to present your issue?

Comment: You are using terrible legacy classes that were supplanted years ago by the modern *java.time* classes defined in JSR 310. Covered many times already on Stack Overflow.

Comment: There are *many* existing Questions on date-time values and the Android time picker. Surely you were diligent in searching and studying those before posting here. To improve your Question, explain how none of those addressed your issue.